# How to parametrize a hermitian matrix $H$ when it commutes with a group $G$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let's say we have a representation $\Gamma$ of a group $G$, and we have a hermitian matrix $H$ commute with all the elements of the group, i.e., $[H,\Gamma(g)]=0,\forall g\in G$. How can we parametrize the hermitian matrix $H$?

For example, if we have a $2\times 2$ hermitian matrix $H$, we can write it as $a \sigma_x+b\sigma_y+c\sigma_z+dI$, where $\sigma_i$ are pauli matrices:
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\sigma _{1}=\sigma _{\mathrm {x} }&={\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}}\\\sigma _{2}=\sigma _{\mathrm {y} }&={\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}}\\\sigma _{3}=\sigma _{\mathrm {z} }&={\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}}\\\end{aligned}}}$$ and $I$ is identity matrix. If this matrix $H$ commute with the group $(I,\sigma_z)$, then we know that $H$ must be diagonal, that is it must be of the form $c\sigma_z+dI$.

But for the general problem, if we know a hermitian matrix(or just a matrix, not necessarily to be hermitian) commute with a representation $\Gamma$ of a group $G$, how can we parametrize the matrix $H$? I've just started to learn the representation theory of a group, but with the basic theory of representation of a group(I read Cornwell's group theory in physics: an introduction), I can't see how to solve it. So are there some hints about how to solve it or some references about how to solve it, because I think the knowledge I need is out of the range of the book that I read now?

Comment: Grammatically, it seems to me we talk about parametrizing *sets* of things, not individual things (e.g. matrices).

Answer (score 1):

Any unitary rep $U$ will be of the form $U_1^{\oplus m_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus U_k^{\oplus m_k}$ where $U_1,\cdots,U_k$ is a list of all irreps, the $m_i$s are the multiplicities, and the direct sums are orthogonal. Suppose $H$ commutes with all $\rho(g)$s, where $\rho:G\to U(V)$ is the unitary repr and $g\in G$ runs over all possible group elements. Then it can be represented in the form $H=H_1\oplus\cdots\oplus H_k$, where $H_i$ is an $m_i\times m_i$ matrix acting on $U_i^{\oplus m_i}$ via acting on each copy of $U_i$ by scalars. (This follows from Schur's lemma and hom-distributivity.)

The adjoint of $H$ just replaces each of the $H_i$s with their adjoints, so you if you can parametrize the $m\times m$ self-adjoint matrices you can parametrize the $d\times d$ ones commuting with all $\rho(g)$s (where $d=\dim U$).